# DispatcherTimer will increasing Interval for every time it's used

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, dispatchertimer

I followed an example from Head First C# on DispatcherTimer.

First time I press the button the ticker will increase by 1 second, but the next time I click on the button the ticker will increase by 2 seconds for every second/tick. Third time ticker increases with 3 seconds and so on (1 second is added for every button press).

Why is that and how to i "reset" the ticker Interval so it will only increase by 1 second every time?

Here is code:

```
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
        timer.Start();
        CheckHappiness();
    }
    int i = 0;
    void timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        ticker.Text = "Tick #" + i++;
    }

    private async void CheckHappiness()
    {
        ... code ..
        timer.Stop();
    }
   }
  }
```

Cheers!

Comment: You keep adding event handlers for the Tick event.  So the second time you click the button, the timer_Tick() method will run twice.  Surely not what you intended.  Subscribe the event only once in the constructor.  And use a variable for the Interval property value.

Comment: Also you call `timer.Stop()` in `CheckHappiness` and that could cause your timer not to raise events, based on what `... code ..` does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
```

This line adds the method to the eventhandler everytime you press the button; in which you do an i++ which increases i by one.
When you have two methods doing that at the same time (since the timer ticks on your interval) then you get an increase by two every tick of the timer.